# What's the best approach to creating word-embeddings?

Tags: words, embedding

I would like to obtain word embeddings (vector representation of words).

Do you think it is better to try to directly obtain a word embedding using some neural network approach or is it better to learn character embeddings then, use them to build word embeddings?

Comment: Use the words directly, not the characters. Yann LeCun did a text prediction study years ago where he found much higher accuracy using characters rather than words. That was the only evidence; other studies showed words were better.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you read this article by Ling et al:

```
@Conference{Lingetal2015,
Author = {Wang Ling and Chris Dyer and Alan Black and Isabel Trancoso},
Title = {Two/too simple adaptations of word2vec for syntax problems},
Booktitle = {Proceedings of NAACL},
Year = {2015},
}
```

It contains a guidance on doing word embeddings properly.